# new starter in 74 pontiac with 350 turns over and fires but won't stay running

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, starting, pontiac

My starter went on my 74 Pontiac with a chev 350 (Canadian). It first was not starting sporadically and I would have to crawl under and tap on it to get it going. I got a new starter and now it will turn over and fire but as soon as you stop cranking it quits. any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are two circuits which can run the vehicle: one when starting; one when running. IIRC, the starting circuit provides full voltage to the coil which gives a bit more juice for extra power when starting. As soon as you allow the key to go back from start to run, this circuit is disconnected. This leaves the run circuit. If you don't have power through this circuit, the engine will quit right after you allow the key to go back to the run position. I don't have access to a wiring diagram at the moment, but I believe there should be two power leads going to you coil (as long as it's the old barrel style coil and not HEI). One of the leads will be coming from the starter (the full voltage) and the other will be the low voltage "run" lead. Check the power here with the key in the run position. If you don't get power there, you'll need to trace it back to figure out where the issue is. If you can find a wiring diagram, it will probably help you tremendously.